# What about very long input and yacc /lex?

Tags: yacc

I consider how is solve problem with too long input for yacc and lex. I have got no possibility to control length of length of input and I am afraid of bufferflow attack, for example.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for concern with the code generated by (f)lex or yacc/bison. They will either reallocate buffers and stacks or report an out-of-memory condition.

In general, the traditional configurations of lex and yacc are less willing to use extra memory, so pathological inputs may result in the parse failing with a memory error, but that is not a security issue.

Of course, that does not relieve you of the responsibility to ensure that all of your code is free of buffer overruns. Avoid fixed-length buffers; always check limits; and never assume that a malloc will not return 0.